# Need help porting C function to Python

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to port a C function which calculates a GPS checksum over to Python.  According to the receiving end I am sometimes miscalculating the checksum, so must still have a bug in there.

C code is

```c
void ComputeAsciiChecksum(unsigned char *data, unsigned int len,
                          unsigned char *p1, unsigned char *p2)
{
    unsigned char c,h,l;

    assert(Stack_Low());

    c = 0;
    while (len--) {
        c ^= *data++;
    }
    h = (c>>4);
    l = c & 0xf;
    h += '0';
    if (h > '9') {
        h += 'A'-'9'-1;
    }
    l += '0';
    if (l > '9') {
        l += 'A'-'9'-1;
    }
    *p1 = h;
    *p2 = l;
}
```

My attempt at a Python function is

```py
def calcChecksum(line):
    c = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(line):
        c ^= ord(line[i]) % 256
        i += 1
    return '%02X' % c;
```

Comment: Are you sure `line` doesn't contain a `unicode` object, but rather a `str` (assuming you are on Python 2.x)?  The fact that you `% 256` the result of `ord()` looks suspicious -- for an ordinary string, `ord()` should never return anything outside the range `0` to `255`.

Comment: line should just be a plain ascii string, I am on Python 2.7

Comment: Can you give an input for which it does not correctly calculate the checksum?

Comment: """it should be just a plain ascii string""": never mind what it **should** be, tell us what it **actually** is. Give examples of input which produce correct and incorrect results. Use `print repr(line)` and copy/paste the output into an edit of your question.

Comment: Have you considered creating a simple DIY test harness for the C function and trying that with your "good" and "bad" input and comparing the results with those of your Python function? Are you sure that the problem is not in the subsequent code that sends `line` and the checksum? Do you have a URL for the message layout/format?

Comment: Are you sure that the `len` arg of the C function is the full length of the "line"?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can set up a testing environment to diagnose your problem.

1. Copy the above C function to a file, remove the `assert()` line, and compile it to a shared library with

   ```py
   gcc -shared -o checksum.so checksum.c
   ```

   (If you are on Windows or whatever, do the equivalent of the above.)
2. Copy this code to a Python file:

   ```py
   import ctypes
   import random

   c = ctypes.CDLL("./checksum.so")
   c.ComputeAsciiChecksum.rettype = None
   c.ComputeAsciiChecksum.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_uint,
                                      ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p]

   def compute_ascii_checksum_c(line):
       p1 = ctypes.create_string_buffer(1)
       p2 = ctypes.create_string_buffer(1)
       c.ComputeAsciiChecksum(line, len(line), p1, p2)
       return p1.value + p2.value

   def compute_ascii_checksum_py(line):
       c = 0
       i = 0
       while i < len(line):
           c ^= ord(line[i]) % 256
           i += 1
       return '%02X' % c;
   ```

Now you have access to both versions of the checksum function and can compare the results.  I wasn't able to find any differences.

(BTW, how are you computing the length of the string in C?  If you are using `strlen()`, this would stop at NUL bytes.)

As a side note, your Python version isn't really idiomatic Python.  Here are two more idiomatic versions:

```py
def compute_ascii_checksum_py(line):
    checksum = 0
    for c in line:
        checksum ^= ord(c)
    return "%02X" % checksum
```

or

```py
def compute_ascii_checksum_py(line):
    return "%02X" % reduce(operator.xor, map(ord, line))
```

Note that these implementations should do exactly the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [this cookbook recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/358258-gps-message-checksums/)? It hints at what input you should include in "line", returns a asterisk in front of the checksum, and gives one (input, output) data pair that you can use as test data.

Are you sure that "the receiver" is working correctly? Is the problem due to upper vs lower case hex letters?